# Capture real time `stdout` and `stderr` when run a function in a process python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, stdout

I have a python function and want to run it as a separate process with `multiprocessing` package.

```
def run(ctx: Context):
    print("hello world!")
    return ctx
```

afterward running it as a separate process with the following script:

```
import multiprocessing

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=(ctx, ))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Now, I need to capture live `stdout` and `stderr` of the above process. Is there any way like as:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python','fake_utility.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
    break
```

But I need to pass the function not running a command with `Popen`. Do you know how can I read `stdout` when I run my function in a separate process?

Comment: You could create a wrapper function which redirects the output of the process before it calls the actual function.

Comment: Could you please make an example? I didn't get your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to create a custom context manager that can temporarily replace `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` with `io.String()` instances to capture the output and return this. For this you need to make the *target* of your `Process` a new function that can setup the context manager and return the results, for which a `multiprocessing.Queue` is used (this, by the way, would be needed anyway if you expect `run` to return its result back to the main process):

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

from io import StringIO
import sys

class CaptureOutput:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout_output = ''
        self._stderr_output = ''

        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = StringIO()

        self._stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stderr = StringIO()

        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self._stdout_output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
        sys.stdout = self._stdout

        self._stderr_output = sys.stderr.getvalue()
        sys.stderr = self._stderr

    def get_stdout(self):
        return self._stdout_output

    def get_stderr(self):
        return self._stderr_output


def run(ctx):
    print("hello world!")
    print("It works!", file=sys.stderr)
    raise Exception('Oh oh!') # Comment out to have a successful completion
    return ctx

def worker(ctx, queue):
    import traceback

    with CaptureOutput() as capturer:
        try:
            result = run(ctx)
        except Exception as e:
            result = e
            print(traceback.format_exc(), file=sys.stderr)
    queue.put((result, capturer.get_stdout(), capturer.get_stderr()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    ctx = None # for demo purposes
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(ctx, queue))
    p.start()
    # Must do this call before call to join:
    result, stdout_output, stderr_output = queue.get()
    p.join()
    print('stdout:', stdout_output)
    print('stderr:', stderr_output)
```

Prints:

```None
stdout: hello world!

stderr: It works!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 44, in worker
    result = run(ctx)
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 36, in run
    raise Exception('Oh oh!') # Comment out to have a successful completion
Exception: Oh oh!
```